Flutter Bloc emit state NOT Triggering state change for BlocBuilder
My initial state set in my Bloc constructor super call WILL trigger the BlocBuilder, but no state changes after that will work.  Yes, my state class is extending Equatable. I have gone through every topic on SO regarding bloc emit state not working and have checked everything. The only difference in this app as opposed to other apps I have bloc working, is that I have a Cubit and Bloc in this app, that should not matter I don't think. Other than that, for the life of me, I cannot figure out what the problem is here.
I initiate a new Bloc event with get_it like this:
getIt<LocationBloc>().add(GetLocation( LocationRequestModel() );
main.dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
           BlocProvider(create: (context) => PlacesCubit()),
           BlocProvider(create: (conetxt) => LocationBloc(getIt())),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          title: 'Great Places',
          theme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
          routerConfig: _appRouter.config(),
        ));
  }

UI / Widget
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        decoration: boxWithBorder(context),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: 170,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: _locationBloc(),
        ...
        ...

_locationBloc() {
    return BlocBuilder<LocationBloc, LocationState>(
        builder: (ctx, state) {
      if (state is LocationNotInitiated) {
        return _noLocationText(false);
      } else if (state is LocationLoading) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else if (state is GetLocationError) {
        return _noLocationText(true);
      }
      //TODO sucess here!
      return const Column();
    });
  }

state class
abstract class LocationState extends Equatable {

  const LocationState();

   @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class LocationNotInitiated extends LocationState {
  const LocationNotInitiated();
  
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class LocationLoading extends LocationState {
  const LocationLoading({required this.test});
  
  final String test;


  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [test];
}

bloc
class LocationBloc extends Bloc<LocationEvent, LocationState> {
  final GetLocationUseCase _getLocationUseCase;

  LocationBloc(this._getLocationUseCase) : super(const LocationNotInitiated()) {
    on<GetLocation>(
      (event, emit) async {
        
        //just testing here
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 250));
        
        // LocationLoading state will not be emitted!
        emit(const LocationLoading(test:"testing"));

      },
    );
      

  }
}


Blocs are created here:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
           BlocProvider(create: (context) => PlacesCubit()),
           BlocProvider(create: (conetxt) => LocationBloc(getIt())),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          title: 'Great Places',
          theme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
          routerConfig: _appRouter.config(),
        ));
  }

This means that you don't get them from getIt. So, when you were trying to fire event with:
getIt().add(GetLocation( LocationRequestModel() );

it gave you some other bloc instance. when you do:
context.read<LocationBloc>().add(GetLocation(LocationRequestModel())

you've got correct instance, that were created in the tree above.
and of course it's no matter that you have and bloc, and cubits in your app.

Yes, you are right. Why get_it works in my other app is because  I load an event up front  where the Bloc is created using get_it -----> create: (context) => getIt()..add(LoadGroceryListItems()),

I changed the way I initiated my event from using get_it to Bloc's :
 context.read<LocationBloc>().add(GetLocation(LocationRequestModel())

and now I see states being propagated back to my LocationBloc.
So that fixes the issue in this app but raises the question: Why does get_it not work in this app to trigger bloc events  but works in other apps I have worked on. I did try registerFactory and registerSingleton and neither worked for injecting Bloc (and receiving events).
